# How to make auto remove from DataBase with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class which contains list of another class:

```
public class Book
{
   ...

   [DataMember]
   public virtual IList<BookOption> Options { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

When I am trying to update one of my books, I am also updating changed records in Options list and I am adding new one, I they were added. So everything looks fine.
I am using NHibernate (not fluent one).

**The problem is**: As I understand, NHibernate has no problem with detecting, when object (BookOption) should be updated or inserted in database, **but what about removing?**
In some cases, some of old Book options are absent (removed) in updated Book version. I need only existing Options (in last version) so I need to remove not used anymore from database, but instead, I'm only adding new ones to them (old options are still in database after Book update).

I can make it with additional method (specially for Option removing), but... I want to try something else before doing it.

Can NHibernate offer something to remove records from database if they are not existing in object list?

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nHibernate provides an option in collection mapping for this purpose: `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`

You can read it in more details here:
[Cascading lifecycle](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-cascades)

Comment: Well, I figured it out already but... still nice that someone answered :) You da real MVP